# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Confirmed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

como esta?

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando traer el ultimo valor de dataDetailsCountry y luego a confirmed,

foto del arbol de redux:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 const casos = dataDetailsCountry[dataDetailsCountry.length -1] //este codigo solo me trae el ultimo array del arbol de redux
```

Con el codigo de arriba, he logrado traer el ultimo valor que tiene "dataDetailsCountry", todo bien hasta aqui,  me imprime los siguientes valores: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien lo que ando intentando es traerme solamente "Confirmed" que por ahora tiene un valor de 11633

Mis intento de traer la variable confirmed fueron estos:

```js
const casos = dataDetailsCountry[dataDetailsCountry.length -1].Confirmed

const casos = dataDetailsCountry && dataDetailsCountry[dataDetailsCountry.length -1].Confirmed
```

Ahora bien, como podría traerme solamente "confirmed" ?

La api que estoy usando es: [API](https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/mx)

Comment: `const {Confirmed:casos } = dataDetailsCountry[dataDetailsCountry.length -1]` podrías utilizar destructuring

Comment: Sigo igual, por laguna razón no se por que no puedo llamar  la acción así, aun me siigue saliendo ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Confirmed' of undefined

Comment: Ahora mismo no podemos ayudarte, la pregunta parece incompleta, ya que no vemos en totalidad el objeto/array al cual deseas acceder, podrias publicar la `API` que estas utilizando?. En mi caso por ejemplo una api con similares datos me los enviaba en `features` y recien podia ingresar al resto.

Comment: Hi Shassain, he actualizado el post